# Is there a way to implement "find or aggregate" using single operation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of simple documents like:

```
{tag: "...", data: {...}}
```

What i want to do is to find a document with given tag and make a projection from its data. But if this document cannot be found, i want to aggregate data from another documents.

I wonder if there is a way to make it using single operation.

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that.

Comment: You could use a query to return all you aggregate, but ordered in a way that if the best match is returned, it's the first one. But without more details on your data or what you want to return, it's hard to help more.

Comment: could you explain what you meant by the statement - *using the only operation*. Please also include, sample insert scripts, and the output that you would expect for possible scenarios. It definitely is not possible using only `find()`. But may be possible using the aggregation framework or any custom server side functions.

Comment: @batscream I meant single operation